# Best case for z170A M7 and Corsair Hydro H100i V2

Tags: motherboard, case, cooling

I'm currently search for a new custom PC and one of the hardest part to me is to choose what case should i go to.

I'm looking for a case that can fit perfectly the motherboard `MSI Z170A M7` and the cpu cooler `Corsair H100i V2` and the requirements are:

- It was good space inside, but dont to be very big outside
- Can implement a good ventilation system (at least 2 fans on the bottom front, and 1 on back top), the place to install the H100i should be on the top since the heated air tend to go up and not down.
- Filters for fans
- Space for the list of components bellow.
- At least space for one optical drive,
- For last the price as an important factor.

This will be the list of components that I'm thinking, since it can help on te decision of the case.

- MSI z170A M7
- I7 6700k
- Samsung 950 512GB M.2
- Corsair Vengence 16(2x8)GB 3200MHZ
- Corsair H100i V2
- Corsair RM750x
- GPU still thinking, but consider Gtx 1070 or 1080.
- On the future it will be added a second Samsung 950 512GB M.2 for raid 0 and a ide for data.

So I'm looking for the best case for the setup and the pros and cons of the case.

Thanks.

PS. I'm not into the led fancing thing but if the case is the best and has leds i don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a ATX case. I have a few suggestions for you. Consider the LIAN LI PC-A05FNB or the Antec Sonata Series SOLO II.

For comparision I have listed the Fractal Design Define R5, which is my favorite case. However, it is too large for your requirements ("but dont to be very big outside"). It's dimensions are 17.76" x 9.13" x 20.51". You seem to want something smaller.

Three smaller cases are listed below. I only have experience with the Antec Sonata Series SOLO II. It's an older design, and it is missing some of the touches found in the R5, but it is a good quality case and it seems to be about the size you are seeking.

However, the LIAN LI PC-A05FNB has very positive reviews. It is worth considering.

The very smallest ATX case I know is the Cooler Master Elite 361. I have not used it. I think it is a older design, also probably lacking the modern features of the R5.

The Pros and Cons below are all from NewEgg reviews. (I summarized.)

**Fractal Design Define R5** Blackout Window Silent ATX Midtower Computer Case

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16811352057
- 5 stars, 23 reviews $109.99
- Pros: very popular quiet case; excellent build quality; well thought out design elements; great value.
- Cons: not a compact, small case (for those looking for something compact)
- Dimensions (H x W x D):

  ```
  18.19" x 9.13" x 20.91" with feet/screws/protrusions
  17.76" x 9.13" x 20.51"
  Weight: 22.69 lbs.
  ```

**Cooler Master Elite 361** - Mid Tower Computer Case with Rotatable Logo for Vertical or Horizontal Placement

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119262
- 4 stars, 17 reviews
- Pros: Great size if you need something compact with full atx. Can fit a moderately large GPU in the case.
- Cons: Can't fit any tall cpu coolers in this case. May be too small for many builds.
- Dimensions (H x W x D):

  ```
  14.40" x 5.90" x 18.20"
  Weight: 10.60 lbs.
  ```

**Antec Sonata Series SOLO II** Black Aluminum / Steel ATX Mid Tower Computer Case

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811129177
- 4 stars, 53 reviews $119.99
- Compact, good quality; not on the same level as the R5, but better than most cases I've used
- Dimensions (H x W x D):

  ```
  18.50" x 8.10" x 17.30"
  Weight: 20.20 lbs.
  ```

**LIAN LI PC-A05FNB** Black Aluminum ATX Mid Tower Computer Case

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811112331
- 4 stars, 51 reviews $89.99
- Pros: One of the best cases I've ever owned.  The front power supply position is an excellent use a space. Everything well thought out and designed. Beautiful finish.
- Cons: This case really can fit a full size ATX board, power supply and GPU, but it becomes a very tight fit when using full size parts. If you are patient then you can assemble this well even with full size parts. Just don't expect to open it up and tinker with it often!
- Dimensions (H x W x D)

  ```
  19.69" x 8.27" x 15.16"
  Weight: 9.70 lbs.
  ```

### UPDATE

I personally prefer Fractal Design cases. Here are three more possibilities to consider. Of these, the Core 2300 is the smallest. However, the Core line is their budget line. I haven't used any of these cases, but they may lack some of the high end features of the R5 (and R4).

** Fractal Design Arc Midi R2 Black Window High-Airflow ATX Midtower Computer Case **

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811352031
- 5 stars, 178 reviews $109.99
- Tweaktown Must Have Editor's Choice Award
- Pros: "By far the best case I have ever bought, and I've purchased many different cases."
- Cons: only 2 external drive bays; heavy; SSD mount has to be placed before putting on your mobo
- Dimensions (H x W x D):

  ```
  18.11" x 9.06" x 20.28"
  Weight:  23.59 lbs.
  ```

** Fractal Design Define R4 Black Silent ATX Midtower Computer Case **

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811352020
- 5 stars, 494 reviews $109.99
- Pros: Very solidly built, lots of cable routing options. Despite its quiet design, there is still good airflow. "It's the best case i have used so far."
- Cons: "A little bigger than I expected"
- Dimensions (H x W x D)

  ```
  18.27" x 9.13" x 20.59"
  Weight:  27.12 lbs.
  ```

** Fractal Design Core 2300 Black Wide-body ATX Midtower Computer Case **

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16811352042
- 4 stars, 11 reviews $69.99
- Benchmark Review's Recommended Product Award
- A compact full-ATX case with bottom-mounted PSU, designed for exceptional airflow and cooling.
- Pros: "This is really a great case for a good price with a quality name behind it. The case is sturdy and well designed. Plenty of space for cable management and plenty of sources to tie down wires."
- Cons: Lower build quality than the R5; some claim flimsy; drive mounts are controversial
- Dimensions (W x H x D)

  ```
  7.6 x 17.5 x 18.1 inches (195 x 445 x 460mm)
  Weight: 11.4 lbs (5.2kg)
  ```

Comment: I liked the Fractal Design Define R5. Seems prety solid and the fans are just in the right place no more no less.

Comment: The Fractal Design Define R5 is a very nice case! It is mid-size ATX. If you have room for it, I think you'll be very happy with it. I did replace my fans with Noctua, but the stock fans are pretty good.